# WHy does google insight ask to serve static assets with an efficient cache policy for images with expiry?

Tags: cache-control, pagespeed-insights

Previously as I tested in google insights, it list down a number of images, css and js files that could be added expiry date at least that's what I understood for this :

> Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy

So I'm testing by adding an image into aws s3 bucket and set duration for 7 days. as I checked in Chrome dev tool, it does show `Cache-Control: max-age=604800`. Size says fetched from memory and status code is 304.

But now as I test again in google page speed insights,it still shows this particular image under

> Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy

section.

If the expiry/longer duration is added as per what suggested, why would it still show the image here? Is there anything else that I should do to make this static file served correctly?

Answer (score 0):

[Google's Lighthouse suggests](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/cache-policy) suggests a year, but also explains that its heuristic is more general than a hardcoded limit.

If you'd like to follow their advice, it's simplest to use a year, although a smaller value should pass the check.

From the example:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
```

> When possible, cache immutable static assets for a long time, **such as a year or longer**. Configure your build tool to embed a hash in your static asset filenames so that each one is unique.

The heuristic is explained as being derived from real statistics, rather than having a particular value:

> This estimate includes some calculations of optimal cache duration for each resource, **based on aggregate usage statistics reported to Chrome.** A longer duration is not necessarily better. Check out the audit source for details. Ultimately, it's up to you to decide what the optimal cache duration is for your resources.

In [the source code](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/1098f952d5c75b22668aa572532415f81d2817af/lighthouse-core/audits/byte-efficiency/uses-long-cache-ttl.js) you can see how the heuristic is defined:

```
// Ignore assets that have very high likelihood of cache hit
const IGNORE_THRESHOLD_IN_PERCENT = 0.925;

...

const cacheHitProbability = CacheHeaders.getCacheHitProbability(cacheLifetimeInSeconds);
if (cacheHitProbability > IGNORE_THRESHOLD_IN_PERCENT) continue;

...
static getCacheHitProbability(maxAgeInSeconds) {
// This array contains the hand wavy distribution of the age of a resource in hours at the time of
// cache hit at 0th, 10th, 20th, 30th, etc percentiles.
// Example: a max-age of 12 hours already covers ~50% of cases, doubling to 24 hours covers ~10% more.
...
const RESOURCE_AGE_IN_HOURS_DECILES = [0, 0.2, 1, 3, 8, 12, 24, 48, 72, 168, 8760, Infinity];
assert.ok(RESOURCE_AGE_IN_HOURS_DECILES.length === 12, 'deciles 0-10 and 1 for overflow');
```

Long story short: I believe the threshold is at around three months (around `max-age=8337600`), but it's unlikely that matching the exact value is more useful than picking a year.